# Postgres Regex_Replace : using pattern in replace string

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

**Requirement**
My requirement is to check if the name of a person contains Initials ,  replace it with Caps of that letter and period. For my requirement initials will always be single letters names , or single letter strings in the name before of after a space.

**Challenge**
I am using REGEXP_REPLACE and use \y to search for a single character within word boundary. This is working fine but now i need to use that same character in my replace string and make it Caps and add a period. Basically the $1 in below query should be replaced with the string i get from the pattern \y[(A-Z)(a-z)]\y

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name,'\y[(A-Z)(a-z)]\y',upper($1|| '.'),'g' )from public.regextest
```

**Sample data**

```
Below is table of sample data and code to create sample data

first_name  Suggested value
A           A.
H M         H. M.
Lars E      Lars E.
Jo          Jo
BO          Bo
X X X       X. X. X.
M HAMED     M. HAMED
M P Rajan   M. P. Rajan
Rajan M P   Rajan M. P.
```

Below is code to create the sample data .

```
create table public.regextest( first_name varchar(100))
insert into  public.regextest values ( 'A')
,('H M')
,('Lars E')
,('Jo')
,('BO')
,('X X X')
,('M HAMED')
,('M P Rajan')
,('Rajan M P')
```

Comment: None of your sample first names have a lower case. I presume `Lars e` would be `Lars E.`? And thank you for the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the replacement, then use [`initcap`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to capitalize the first letter of each word.

```
select
  initcap(
    regexp_replace(first_name, '\y([[:alpha:]])\y(?!\.)', '\1.','g')
  )
from public.regextest
```

The character class `[[:alpha:]]` matches all alphabetical characters, including accented ones. Flanking it with `\y` ensures we match only one. `(?!\.)` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php) checking that it is *not* followed by a `.` without consuming that `.` in the match, that avoids doubling up. It's surrounded by `()` to capture it.

Then the replacement is the captured character, Postgres uses `\1`, with a dot.

Feed the result into `initcap` to fix the capitalization.

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b811033fb2026ee9c4b2c68fb8cd9ffd).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution you provided works for me!

Comment: One issue i observed is when the name already has a period in it . Something like A. gets replaced as A.. , how can we avoid this ? We can obviously write another replace statement and replace all .. with a single . but that might not be best way to do it.

Comment: @Vivek Good observation. It needs a [negative lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php) to spot the `.` without consuming it.